# c++ win32 change trackbar background color

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, trackbar

I have a win32 API, developed in c++ and i can't find any useful information regarding how can i change the background color of a Trackbar component in windows Vista and above?

I am looking for a equivalent to .NET attribute called BackColor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winforms implements it by handling [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787524%28VS.85%29.aspx) for a TrackBar control.  The example code in the linked SDK article should do the trick.

Comment: did the trick! The 2 lines of code needed: case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH); Do you happen to know how would i change the trackbar channel  size(TBM_GETCHANNELRECT)? There is only a getter no setters.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486075%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Start a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not done that one before, but try using [NM_CUSTOMDRAW for trackbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then setting the background brush and text colour of the DC for that control when its being drawn (probably in the CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTERASE stage).